# Theme, Plugin or Both?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

So I've developed a WP theme I'm running to house learning materials at my uni and I want to share it in the theme or plugin directory. When I run it through the theme checker, some of the back-end functionality (custom post types and filters) is flagged as 'This is not a theme!', so I'm wondering how to best approach the project now. Essentially the look and feel can't be separated from the back end functionality, so:

- Can I develop a plugin that includes theme elements?
- Should I separate it out into a theme and plugin that really need to be installed together?

Any thoughts or feedback welcome

Current site is here for reference: https://edtech.une.edu.au/books/introtoedtech/learningwithtech/

Comment: "Essentially the look and feel can't be separated from the back end functionality". -why not? WP sites do this all the time. The theme checker is complaining because the flagged functionality is site-specific, not theme-specific. Ideally, that functionality should be in a functionality plugin, so the _theme_ can be replaced without affecting basic _site_ functionality (and to minimize the risk of front-end devs breaking anything important).

Comment: The integrated plugin / theme I developed relies heavily on custom post types, and Pages aren't even included in the theme side of things (i.e. pages aren't displayed at all). As the separated plugin and theme are linked through the CPT, I'd rather not have to package them separately, but as one 'platform'. Any guidance on how make this simpler for users would be great!